# VS Code - No module named 'streamlit'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, download, streamlit

I am trying to use VS Code and I am importing some modules (for example : pandas and streamlit). The terminal of VS Code tells me "No module named pandas" or "No module named streamlit" whereas it is downloaded on my computer.

VS Code:

[image]

Terminal of my computer when trying "pip install streamlit":

[image]

Do you know how I could correct this mistake ?

Comment: Are you using a virtual env? It looks like pip and the runtime are two different environments, and streamlit is installed in one and not the other.

Comment: Do you know how I could verify that ? Conda was activated on VS Code ((base) symbol) so I tried to deactivate it and I still have the same mistake

Comment: If you're using anaconda, I'd recommend you install packages with the conda command, such as `conda install -n streamlit` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that the environment is consistent. `pip` installs the library into the real Python environment, and you use the virtual environment.

1. If you want to use it in the virtual environment, please use the
   command `conda install` to install it.
2. If you want to use the real python environment, you can use shortcuts "**Ctrl+shift+P**" and type "**Python: Select Interpreter**" to change the python environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a different env, so before you can import, you will have to append the path of the installed packages to your working environment.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages")

import streamlit as st
```